# Micheal O'Searcoid, Metric Spaces: Problem 8.5:

Tags: metric-spaces

There exists a function $f: X\to Y$ between metric spaces $X$ and $Y$ that is not continuous but has the property that, for each closed ball $B$ of $Y$, $f^{-1}(B)$ is closed in $X$.

What is an example in support of the above statement?

Is this result true for all metric spaces $X$ and $Y$?

If I replace "Closed"  with "Open" in the above problem, then the function is becoming continuous.

Comment: Certainly not: if $X$ and $Y$ are singleton sets, then any map between them is continuous!

Comment: Actually, all we really need is $X$ to be the discrete metric space, and any map from $X$ to any metric space $Y$ will be continuous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: Try $X=[0,2]$, $Y=[0,1)\cup[2,3]$, and

$$f:X\to Y:x\mapsto\begin{cases}
x,&\text{if }0\le x<1\\
x+1,&\text{if }1\le x\le 2\,.
\end{cases}$$

Here $X$ and $Y$ have their usual metrics as subspaces of $\Bbb R$ with its usual metric.

Comment: Teacher can you explain a bit more

Comment: @James: Show that $f$ is not continuous. (HINT: It’s not continuous at $x=1$.) You also need to show that if $B$ is a closed ball in $Y$, then $f^{-1}[B]$ is always a closed ball in $X$. You’ll have to deal with several cases here, depending on where the centre of $B$ is and what it’s radius is, but each of the cases is pretty straightforward.